# Best approach to have users that can add/edit/view but cannot delete items

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups, site-settings, contribute

I have created a new sub site named “Finance” of type team site and it comes with these 3 default groups:-

```
Finance Member -----> Contribute
Finance Owners -----> Full Control
Finance Visitors -----> Read
```

Currently when I add someone to the members group he can delete list items, which I do not want to have. So I did the following septs to prevent memebers from deleting items and pages:-

- I went to the site collection level setting --> site permission --> click on “Permission level”. I click on the built-in “Contribute ” site permission , click on “Copy Permission Level”.
- Then I add a new permission level name “Contribute without delete”, and I un-check these 2 check boxes from the permission list ; “Delete versions” & “Delete items”.so in this case I have a copy of the Contribute permission level but without “Delete versions” & “delete items” permissions…

[image]

- I went back to the subsite permission, and I change the member group to have the new permission level named “Contrite without delete” instead of “Contribute” & the owner group to have the “contribute” level instead of full control. As follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice if this is the correct approach to have users that can view/edit/create, while they can not delete any data from the subsite..?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is correct and is the standard approach.

Comment: This question might be better rephrased into a "how do I allow users to add, edit, and view but not delete items?" question, with the body of most of your post as an answer that can be accepted - because it covers the basic approach quite well

Comment: @EricAlexander but is there other checkboxes (other than Delete items & delete versions) that i need to remove to prevent deleting items including pages, list items or documents ?

Comment: @John-M thanks for the reply,, but are there other check-boxes that i need to un-check to prevent deleting items ?

Comment: no, unchecking `Delete Items` covers all of those cases.

Comment: I had the same thing done in one of my previous cases in project and it worked without any issue. this is the perfect approach.